# how to add gridview in betwwen two edittext in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

i am working on an app notebook app in which I want to add pictures to the note. Please look at the screenshots and also how to scroll gridview and both edit text.  [image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpmYD.jpg)
[image]

This is the XML code of mine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.app.pb.privatenotebook.NoteBrief">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Subject"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Note"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_cre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.app.pb.privatenotebook.NoteBrief">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Subject"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp" />

 <GridView 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="3"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Note"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_cre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i have a question. you write columnwidth=1 it means they show only one image in a row. but in pic you can add max 3 pic in row

Comment: Ya  change it to 3 like this,    android:numColumns="3"